# How to optimize (maximize) a function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to optimize an equation in R, but it seems like I can only minimize it. My question is: How do I maximize my equation?

```
p = 0.00379
W_0 = 0.3*10^6
L = 0.1489*10^6

u <- function(x,n){
  if(n != 1){
    (x^{1-n})/1-n
  }
  else{
    log(x)
  }
}

aslan <- function(a,n,l){
  p*u(W_0-L+a*L-a*p*L*(1+l),n)+(1-p)*u(W_0-a*p*L*(1+l),n)
}
optimize(aslan,c(0,1),n=0.8,l=0.5)
```

Comment: `optimize(aslan,c(0,1),n=0.8,l=0.5, maximum = T)`?

Comment: Why `.../1` in `(x^{1-n})/1-n` ?

Comment: Eventually you want: `p = 0.00379;
W_0 = 0.3e6;
L = 0.1489e6;

u <- function(x,n) {
  if (n == 1) return(log(x));
  x^(1-n)/(1-n)
}`

Comment: @bellmaneqn Thank you! That and the fix of '.../n' instead of '.../(n-)' fixed it. The result i get looks like this though:
     $maximum
     [1] 0.1964876

     $objective
     [1] 62.25678

And I want to get just the number, as I need to use it for a later calculation. Anyone that can help?

Comment: @SørenThode `result <- optimize(...); result$maximum; result$objective`